# Selenium Firefox does not open when called from MVC app deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iis

I'm trying to run below code within a controller in Asp.net MVC 5:

`var driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);`

It works when I'm using IIS Express, but the browser is not opened when I'm using IIS. Do we need to do something in IIS setting to make it work?

Comment: Update the question with the error you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

Try using RemoteWebDriver rather than FirefoxDriver

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");
string serverURL = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(serverURL), capabilities);
```